# Typo3 v9.5 BE login not working after fresh installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have installed fresh TYPO3 v9.5 in my local server. After complete installation i open the backed and then try to login with my username and password but every time i getting error. see below screenshot.
[image]

I try to search many solution for this but not getting success. I know about Argon2i password Hashing problems for new fresh Typo3 v9 installation. So, i select another password Hashing method via `INSTALL TOOL`. But still i am getting same error. Sometime i clear whole cache via install tool and open the back end, but when i enter my username and password will getting same error.

Someone help please.

Comment: How looks the URL of this site can't be reached?

Comment: i used WAMP in my windows systems. Also i have configure virtual host in my local systems. So, when i enter my url like **typo3demo.com/typo3/** then it's give error like above.

Comment: It don't looks like a password problem. May you found more details in your PHP error log or Apache error log.

Comment: If you're using Linux, probably the issue is directory permission. Your directory should be writable. If you don't have proper permission, TYPO3 unable to create a cache file which causes an issue. Use `sudo chmod 777 -R projectPath/` (Just for example don't use 777 at live server ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is associate with Apache. In Windows case you have to include in `httpd.conf` next lines:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Last thing you have to take into account with installation in Windows beacuse you should configure `ssl` in this system, is more easy in a Unix distribution based.

You could follow the tutorial in https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/tutorial-update-typo3-9lts-testsystem-windows-installieren/?cn-reloaded=1 , the only thing is this written in german.

Answer (score 0):

I **uncomment** below line in **httpd.conf** file.

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

And added below code in **httpd-mpm.conf** file and it's work fine for me.

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```